# R Split dataframe by new line in column

Tags: regex, r, substring

I'm trying to split strings within a column by new-line "\n".
Here is a dataframe sample_data:

```
 test_data <- data.frame(ID=c('john@xxx.com', 'sally@xxx.com'),
                  Changes=c('3 max cost changes
  productxyz > pb100  > a : Max cost decreased from $0.98 to $0.83
  productxyz > pb2  > a : Max cost decreased from $1.07 to $0.91
  productxyz > pb2  > b : Max cost decreased from $0.65 to $0.55', 
                            '2 max cost changes
  productabc > pb1000  > d : Max cost decreased from $1.07 to $0.91
  productabc > pb1000  > x : Max cost decreased from $1.44 to $1.22'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

My goal is to extract the prices into columns and obtain a result set like this:

```
ID              Prev_Price    New_Price
john@xxx.com     $0.98            $0.83
john@xxx.com     $1.07            $0.91
john@xxx.com     $0.65            $0.55
sally@xxx.com    $1.07            $0.91
sally@xxx.com    $1.44            $1.22
```

I've tried using tidyr package but my result is full of N/A.

```
vars <- c("Prev_Price","New_Price")
seperate(sample_data, Changes, into = vars, sep = "[A-Za-z]+from", extra= "drop")
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
df1$ID <- df1$ID[df1$ID!=''][cumsum(df1$ID!='')]
library(stringi)
setNames(data.frame(df1$ID, do.call(rbind,stri_extract_all(df1$Changes, 
       regex='\\$\\d*'))), c('ID', 'Prev_Price', 'New_Price'))
 #   ID Prev_Price New_Price
 #1  A        $20       $10
 #2  A        $11       $10
 #3  B        $13       $12
 #4  B        $15       $12
```

Or

```
library(tidyr)
extract(df1, Changes, into=c('Prev_Price', 'New_Price'), 
          '[^$]*(\\$\\d*)[^$]*(\\$\\d*)')
#   ID Prev_Price New_Price
#1  A        $20       $10
#2  A        $11       $10
#3  B        $13       $12
#4  B        $15       $12
```

Or

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
setDT(df1)[, c('Prev_Price', 'New_Price') := tstrsplit(Changes, 
                                 '[A-Za-z ]+')[-1]][]
#   ID              Changes Prev_Price New_Price
#1:  A down from $20 to $10        $20       $10
#2:  A down from $11 to $10        $11       $10
#3:  B down from $13 to $12        $13       $12
#4:  B down from $15 to $12        $15       $12
```

NOTE: The "Changes" can be removed

Or using only `base R` methods

```
data.frame(ID=df1$ID, read.table(text=gsub('[^$]*(\\$\\d+)', ' \\1 ', 
   df1$Changes),col.names=c('Prev_Price', 'New_Price'), 
                    stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
 #   ID Prev_Price New_Price
 #1  A        $20       $10
 #2  A        $11       $10
 #3  B        $13       $12
 #4  B        $15       $12
```

#### Update

If the elements reside in the same cell, one option would be using the devel version of `data.table` ie. v1.9.5+.  It can be installed from [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

Here, we use the same code to split the 'Changes'  (`tstrsplit(Changes,..)`), then `melt` the output to long form by specifying the `measure.vars` as a `list`, and if needed `order` by 'ID' and remove the unwanted columns ('variable').

```
 melt(
   setDT(df2)[, paste0('V',1:4) := tstrsplit(Changes,
           '[A-Za-z ]+')[-1]][,-2, with=FALSE],
      id.var='ID', measure=list(c('V1', 'V3'), c('V2', 'V4')), 
        value.name=c('Prev_Price', 'New_Price'))[order(ID)][, variable:=NULL]
  #    ID Prev_Price New_Price
  #1:  A        $20       $10
  #2:  A        $11       $10
  #3:  B        $13       $12
  #4:  B        $15       $12
```

Or we can use `gsub` as before and then convert to `long` format with `reshape` from `base R`

```
 d1 <- data.frame(ID=df2$ID,read.table(text=gsub('[^$]*(\\$\\d+)',
                 ' \\1 ', df2$Changes)))

colnames(d1)[-1] <- paste0(c('Prev_Price.', 'New_Price.'), 
                          rep(1:2,each=2))
reshape(d1, idvar='ID', varying=2:ncol(d1), sep=".", direction='long')
#    ID time Prev_Price New_Price
#A.1  A    1        $20       $10
#B.1  B    1        $13       $12
#A.2  A    2        $11       $10
#B.2  B    2        $15       $12
```

#### Update2

For the new dataset ("df3"), we can use `stri_extract_all_regex` to extract the `$` followed by numbers including the decimals (`'\\$[0-9.]+'`) for the "Changes" column, use `Map` to combine the first column with the `list` output we got from the `stri_extract_all_regex` after changing the output to a `matrix` (as we need the alternating elements to be in different columns), and then `rbind` (`do.call(rbind,`).

```
library(stringi)
res <- do.call(rbind,
       Map(function(x,y) data.frame(x,matrix(y, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE, 
           dimnames=list(NULL, c("Prev_Price", "New_Price")))),
        df3$ID, stri_extract_all_regex(df3$Changes, '\\$[0-9.]+')))
row.names(res) <- NULL
res
#              x Prev_Price New_Price
#1  john@xxx.com      $0.98     $0.83
#2  john@xxx.com      $1.07     $0.91
#3  john@xxx.com      $0.65     $0.55
#4 sally@xxx.com      $1.07     $0.91
#5 sally@xxx.com      $1.44     $1.22
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "", "B", ""), 
 Changes = c("down from $20 to $10", 
"down from $11 to $10", "down from $13 to $12", "down from $15 to $12"
)), .Names = c("ID", "Changes"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -4L))

df2 <- data.frame(ID=c('A', 'B'),
   Changes=c('down from $20 to $10 down from $11 to $10', 
  'down from $13 to $12 down from $15 to $12'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: @user3116753  Updated with some possible options

Comment: @user3116753 Here we are extracting all instances where there is a dollar followed by numbers with decimals (or not).  It returns the output as a list, which we then,cbind with the first column using `Map` after changing the output to a matrix (as it will get in the format you wanted), and then rbind the output

Comment: @user3116753  Just practise.  I would say create some random strings for example `str1 <- '1234 have no :7'` and try to extract the number following the `:` or the non-numeric part, numeric part etc, and then try it on complex strings.  You will learn it faster

Comment: @user3116753 Try `library(stringr);str_extract_all(test_data$Changes, 'pb\\d+|[A-Za-z]+ (?=:)')`

Comment: @user3116753  I think you are using an older version of `stringr`. In that case, wrap with `perl`, ie. `str_extract_all(test_data$Changes, perl('pb\\d+|[A-Za-z]+ (?=:)'))`

Comment: @user3116753 I guess you can do that.  If you have more questions, please ask as a new question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78099/discussion-between-user3116753-and-akrun).

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c('A','','B',''), Changes=c('down from $20 to $10','down from $11 to $10','down from $13 to $12','down from $15 to $12'), stringsAsFactors=F );
with(list(ss=strsplit(df$Changes,'\\s+')),transform(df,ID=ID[ID!=''][cumsum(ID!='')],Prev_Price=sapply(ss,function(v)v[3]),New_Price=sapply(ss,function(v)v[5]),Changes=NULL));
##   ID Prev_Price New_Price
## 1  A        $20       $10
## 2  A        $11       $10
## 3  B        $13       $12
## 4  B        $15       $12
```

Another approach:

```
with(df,cbind(ID=ID[ID!=''][cumsum(ID!='')],setNames(as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,strsplit(Changes,'\\s+'))[,c(3,5)]),c('Prev_Price','New_Price'))));
## same result
```

Comment: I've added another dataset called test_data to the question. Any help would be much appreciated. Thx